# How to center the grid of a plot on scatter points?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have this scatter plot:

[image]

I'd like to move the grid in a way that each point (green square) would be surrounded by the grid's cells. For example:

[image]

The code to reproduce the plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [24, 24, 24, 16, 16, 2, 2, 2]
x = list(range(0, len(data)))
y = list(range(0, 25))

plt.scatter(x, data, marker='s', c='g', s=100)
plt.yticks(y)
plt.xticks(x)

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the following meets the requirement. You can use the minor ticks for the grid and the major ticks for the labels.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [24, 24, 24, 16, 16, 2, 2, 2]
x = list(range(0, len(data)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, data, marker='s', c='g', s=49)

ax.set_yticks(np.arange(25))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(25+1)-0.5, minor=True)

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(data)))
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(data)+1)-0.5, minor=True)

ax.grid(True, which="minor")
ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to enlarge the plot? I am trying to use `plt.figure(figsize=(3,4))` but it's simply creating another figure

Comment: `figsize=(3,4)` will shrink the plot. You may want to use `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,9))` to actually enlarge it.

Comment: Yeah but it modifies the size of the figure not the size of the plot so it doesn't help

Comment: The axes resides in a figure. It will scale with the figure dimesions. If you make the figure larger, the axes will scale accordingly.

Comment: Mmm nope. Maybe it's because it's a sublopts()?

Comment: Running the code with three different figsizes would result in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrAeR.png).

Comment: The prblem is when you have a long sequence of data. Using fisize=(40, 9) [image](https://ibb.co/9TWgjdW)

Comment: So you are trying to make the figure larger than your screen?

Comment: I don't care about the figure, I just want the plot to be visible.

Comment: Your plot *is* visible. I can only help you if you describe clearly what problem you have.

Comment: I'd like to increase the scale of the plot, in that way the points in the scatter would look bigger.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand "scale of the plot" in this context. The point size is determined by the `s` parameter of the scatter.